# JPA Query/Hibernate: Column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following table `session`:

```
sessionid | user_id | begin (timestamp)
----------+---------+-------------------
     1    |    A    |  1234
     2    |    B    |  4567
     3    |    A    |  8912
     4    |    C    |  3456
```

The table gives information about the sessions of a user. Basically, a session is when a user has performed a successful login.

Now, I want to get a list of the users which have logged in most recently. If a user has more than one login (and occures twice or more in this table), I use the most recent timestamp for it. The list should be ordered by logintime, so that the most recent users are at top of the list.

Using the following SQL query I solved this:

```
SELECT s.user_id, MAX(begin) -- MAX(begin) can be left out, results are the same
FROM session s
GROUP BY s.user_id
ORDER BY MAX(s.begin) DESC
```

However, in my application I am supposed to use a JPA Query for this. So I converted this to the following JPA Query:

```
SELECT s.user
FROM Session s
GROUP BY s.user
ORDER BY MAX(s.begin) DESC
```

I select here the user and not the user_id because User is an Entity in Session. We are using Hibernate as well, and when executing this query, I get the following error:

`ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] ERROR: column "user1_.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

[I found a bug description about this behaviour on Hibernate.](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1615)

Using the `s.user.id` instead works fine, but it gives me only the IDs and I need the user Objects.

I made a workaround now by getting the user ids first and then find the user entities in the database, but this needs an additional database call and seems unperformant to me, as I know that it can be done within one query.

How to solve this problem?

I am not allowed to use SQL queries directly in the application, I must do it using the JPA Query approach.

Comment: Not at a computer, so I can't try it to see if it'd work, but what if you didn't use the group by, but instead selected distinct s.user ordered by s.begin? (Might need to use the join syntax)

Comment: You mean like `SELECT DISTINCT s.user FROM Session s ORDER BY MAX(s.begin) DESC`? If I do so, I get this `ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

Comment: Not quite. leave out the MAX(), just order by s.begin and let the distinct clause combine multiple identical users.

Comment: Although reading the error, it might not actually work...

Comment: @Charlie I left out MAX() now and just ordered by s.begin, but I am still getting the same error.