# Hibernate column "user1_.user_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to write a simple query in hibernate where I just get a descending list of users with the most points. Basically I'm trying to write this query `select user_id from user_points group by user_id order by sum(points) desc`. This works on the Postgres db I'm working on.

I have the following HSQL query `select c.user from UserPoints c  group by c.user order by sum(c.points) desc`. The Points table has a column called user_id which refers to the user table. In our mapping user_id is mapped to a User class.

However when I run this query I get column "user1_.user_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. I tried searching for similar issues but only really came  up with this: [JPA Query/Hibernate: Column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623219/jpa-query-hibernate-column-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an) which is unanswered.

I'm kind of stuck with HQL because the other thing I need to do is join on a table that doesn't have a mapped association (but also has a user_id key). I'm also trying to keep this query as fast as possible. Any help would be really appreciated as I'm really confused as to why this isn't working.

Comment: `select c.user from UserPoints p group by p.user order by sum(c.points) desc`  - I dint see the class for alias `c` ?

Comment: In your query what does "c" refers to?

Comment: Sorry I mistyped my question its supposed to be UserPoints c group by c.user

Comment: You should post your entity classes too.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I may have found what the issue was. We actually have two mappings to the user_id column. One is a property where we have the user_id as just a regular long and the other many to one mapping where we map it to the user class. I set the logging level to debug so I can see the query that hibernate was creating and it seems like it was using turning the select c.user to all the columns in the user table (which means it was using the many to one mapping correctly), but for some reason in the group by clause it was converting c.user to the user_id property. Since I can't change the mapping and I'm on a tight deadline I've opted to just write a regular SQL query to grab the user ids and then run another criteria query to get all the users in that list of ids.